# Rar command - ignore certain folders

Tags: svn, rar

I would like to rar a folder but exclude a certain of folders and all the files beneath them - the .svn folder.

How could I make this happen using the rar console command (rar.exe)?

Comment: I want to exclude file having name with spaces `CEEMEA & LATAM.doc`. What should I do? `"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\rar" a -xCEEMEA & LATAM.doc "abc.rar"`

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried -x.svn*

Comment: Wow. I've been trying through all those options and just can't figure it out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This is not working. Files beneath the .svn folders will still get archived.

Answer (score 3):

I tried the following and it worked for me:

```
RAR a -ehs -x*\.svn\* -r
```

Comment: does not work properly as it does not block the .svn directory itself. instead of -x*\.svn\* put -x*\.svn* to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

```
dir .svn /b /s > files.lst
rar (rest of command) -x@files.lst
```

Comment: This will only work for the top level, but not the sub folders.

Answer (score 1):

You could do an svn export, then you wouldn't have the .svn folders in the first place.

Comment: It seems so obvious, why did no-one think of this before?

Answer (score 0):

**Using a batch file:**

```
1) dir /b /s /a .sv? > svn.lst
2) for /f \"tokens=* delims=\" %%i in ('dir /s /b /a:d *svn') do (dir /b /s /q \"%i\") >> svn.lst
3) rar a -x@svn.lst myarchive [files....]
```

These three lines has to be in a .bat file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the fully qualified path and it's substructures.
The path has to be canonical.

```
popdir %mypath%\.svn
set _=%cd%
pushdir

rar a -x%_% -x%_%\* myarchive
```

Answer (score 0):

**The final working version, *three steps* involved:**

```
(1) dir /b /s /a .sv? > svn.lst 
(2) rar.exe a -r [archive name] . -xsvn.lst -x@svn.lst 
(3) del svn.lst
```